# How to bypass SSL certificate for WSS in React Native?

Tags: react-native, ssl, websocket, ssl-certificate, self-signed-certificate

I'm building an Expo (React Native) app in which I need to talk to multiple internal servers that user self-signed SSL certificates.

I've been able to bypass the SSL issues when making an HTTPS request by using `rn-fetch-blob`.
However, I haven't been able to figure out how to bypass those same issues when using the `Websocket` API.

Is there a way to bypass SSL certificate issues when connecting to `wss://<some-ip>:<some-port>`?

When I try to connect to the `wss://` endpoint on the server, I see an error on the server logs that terminates the connection:

```
Illegal SNI hostname received [49, 50, 55, 46, 48, 46, 48, 46, 49]
```

However, if I disable TLS and use an insecure endpoint `ws://` then it all works fine.

Comment: "Is there a way to bypass SSL certificate issues when connecting to wss://<some-ip>:<some-port>?" That would mean removing all interesting parts you get with WSS regarding protection of channel, at which point it makes no sense to use WSS anymore, just stick to WS. Or use WSS properly, and use a name not an IP address.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I totally agree with your statement, and that's exactly what I mentioned to my superiors. However, I've been asked to do it this way, so I'm trying to figure out if there's a solution.

Comment: And what is their argument explaining how WSS is still useful if bypassing the certificate check? It is just security theatre, the feeling of adding "s" at end of any protocol to mean "secure" and all is done just with that?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I agree. Someone mentioned it would encrypt the data, but I'm with you. If you're bypassing the certificate, then anyone could pretend to be that server and get the data anyway.

The problem is that at this point there are so many of those in the field that it would probably be hard to do that transition. I will push for it, but I bet they'll keep pushing for me to just bypass security.

Just no idea on how to do that in RN. I guess we'd have to dig into native code and change the Websocket implementation.